# Remove an XML node by its content

Tags: c#, xml

I Have a XML file that I want remove a node that it's content is '**test**'.
I search entire Google, so doesn't help me or I can't get my answer.
The XML file content is shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<parent>
  <child>C#</child>
  <child>VB</child>
  <child>VB.net</child>
  <child>F#</child>
  <child>C++</child>
  <child>C</child>
  <child>Ruby</child>
  <child>Pascal</child>
  <child>test</child>
  <child>python</child>
</parent>
```

I can load it to any list. So my address is OK.
But can't remove the node that its content is **test**.

One of my tried code is:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(Address);
XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode("/parent/child[text()='test']");
doc.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node);
doc.Save(Address);
```

any suggestion will be appreciable.

**Update:**  Thanks to **Andrei Vatasescu** the correct answer is:

```
node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node);
```

instead of :

```
doc.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the program as posted originally works fine, there is just one small error: "ParentNode.RemoveChild()" should be called on node instead of doc.

Comment: thanks I Update my post with your correct answer. thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 foreach (XmlNode node in doc.ChildNodes)
 {
      if (node.InnerText == "test")
      {
           doc.RemoveChild(node);
      }
  }
```